# How to draw on a photo immediately after taking it, then use that image for further operation in Xamarin forms

Tags: ios, camera, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, image-editing

I want to allow user to click image from camera and then edit that captured image before uploading it to server (similar to image editor that comes when we are uploading whats app status or sending images on whats app), I am not getting any hints how to do this in Xamarin forms.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: write a custom renderer